# Restore the sharepoint backup(.dat) to another server

Tags: sharepoint-2010

I need to restore the sharepoint backup(.dat) to another server. while restoring
it is giving me version error. my source server have Hot Fix (office2010-kb2394320-fullfile-x64-glb) installed but on destination it is not installed. i have installed Sharepoint 2010 SP1 on destination server. am i doing something wrong?

Please help

Comment: Could you please give us the complete error message (with stack trace from the logs)?

Comment: Your backup is from a different version of Microsoft SharePoint Foundation and cannot be restored to a server running the cur
rent version. The backup file should be restored to a server with version '14.0.0.5128' or later.

Comment: Try this approch: [Restore backup from another version of sharepoint server][1]


  [1]: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/38078/restore-backup-from-another-version-of-sharepoint-server

Answer (score 0):

For SharePoint 2010 backup/restore to work, below are the pre-requisites:

> The source & destination server must be of same configuration WRT the
>   SharePoint software

Meaning same Service Packs, hot fixes......